# All I want for Christmas is a list of burninated tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, blocked-tags

Would it be possible to make the list of blacklisted tags public?

The list would help establish precedence when determining if a tag should be put forward for burnination. This will simplify the task of proposing and evaluating a [tag-blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request).

For example, when I  come across a tag I believe shouldn't be used, I [trawl through past meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=burninate%20%5Btags%5D) in a hope of finding burninated tags that are similar. If I find something similar, I submit a burnination request; otherwise I simply clean up the tags and move on. Having a definitive list will substantially speed up this process.

Comment: Have you been good the whole year long? Otherwise, you know, Christmas wishes are an issue...

Comment: @balpha Bah... in that case, the list is doomed to be kept private :(

Comment: (obligatory xkcd reference: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/incident.png)

Answer (score 6):

It seems like it'd be pretty simple to add a `Burned` tab to the `Tags` page.

[image: Burned Tab]

Comment: It doesn't even have to be that prominent. It could be squirreled away under `/tags/blacklisted` and linked to from the FAQ somewhere.

Comment: BTW, not my dv.